# Skip maven test phase on local

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I want to skip tests before installing my java project just on my local since it's taking too much time. It should keep on working on buildserver.

I know that it can be done on command line but I'm using Intellij and when I click on "Install", I don't want it to run tests.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure about intellij but check if it has a run configurations,if it does you will have a check box to skip tests..

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-maven.html?origin=old_help

Answer (score 8):

Just click on this button before running the install:

[image]

The button might look different or be somewhere else on a different Intellij version. In this case, you can do the following:

Press 2x <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to open the `Search Everywhere` window and search for `Toggle 'Skip Tests' Mode`.

Comment: Awesome. I haven't noticed that feature so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind the button position might be different on the newer version, since this is Intellij14. I updated the answer to avoid this being a problem.

Comment: It's the same icon in IntelliJ 16.